# Linear Approximations & Differentials

Tags: calculus

I've been trying to solve this problem and I just can't figure it out. I've tried to solve it several different ways and still nothing which is probably because we didn't cover this form of a question. Here's the question:

> The linear approximation at x = 0 to 1/sqrt(5-x) is A + Bx where A is:
>   __________ and where B is: ____________.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Note that $f(x) \approx f(x_0) + f'(x_0)(x - x_0)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(5-x\right)^{-1/2}=-\frac{1}{2}\left(5-x\right)^{-3/2}(-1)\rightarrow\frac{1}{10\sqrt{5}}$$

$$A=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}$$
$$  B=\frac{1}{10\sqrt{5}}$$

Comment: Ohh, okay. That's fairly simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So, this essentially involves making an approximation of a function's behavior close to a certain point. The approximation that you make in this case is that the function near that point can just be thought of as its tangent line (thus, why it's called 'linear') at that point. Now, think about what you already know about the relationship between tangent lines and derivatives of functions, and go from there.